# Do published Android apps pay for open source libraries they are using?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

If an android app is using an external library for instance like (Retrofit, EventBus, or GSON), does it have to pay for its service once that same app is published in the Google Play Store (Goes live)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on the licence terms of each individual library. For Retrofit for example, I quickly found this: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/LICENSE.txt which is the Apache licence. It imposes conditions on how you use it, but it doesn't mention that you have to pay the contributors. Other packages may be different - you need to look at each one separately.

Comment: Looks like each library will have a license.txt file that contains permissions on how much of allowance you have in that library usage as far as commercial usage and other right.